# GRUB is not seen during dual boot. How can i get it?

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, windows-10, grub-efi

My laptop is Lenovo G50-70. I had installed ubuntu and it was booting fine from GRUB but windows had a BCD error. After fixing BCD error it straightaway boots into windows 10 without showing GRUB and I am not able to boot into ubuntu. how can i get GRUB back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub menu not showing up at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437621/grub-menu-not-showing-up-at-boot)

Comment: Windows removed grub. You need to re-install it.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed issues like this in the past using the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. You will need to have or create a bootable boot repair disk or a bootable Ubuntu CD or USB.

Comment: or something like: https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/ which I've used in the past

Comment: can u say how did u do that???

Comment: The link on Boot-Repair shows how to add the Boot-Repair tool into your Ubuntu live installer. You can create a bootable flash drive for Boot-Repair, but is often is not as current as downloading the newest from ppa. Also can create super grub or Boot-Repair or other repair tools by downloading ISO and installing to a flash drive or DVD using the same installer tools you used to create the Ubuntu live installer. Be sure to boot in same mode UEFI or BIOS as Windows is installed.